# Can' remove duplicate when use lambda in higher-order function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Here my android app

```
 suspend fun getTraidersList(isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false): Any {
            if (isCustomtHandle) {
                return runOperationWithoutHandle {
                    traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()
                }
            } else {
                return runOperationWithDefaultHandle {
                    traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()
                }    
            }
        }

 suspend fun executeTraderOperation(traderOperation: Trader.Operation, base: String, quote: String, isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false): Any {
            val sender = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "_" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
            val key = DateUtil.getDateAsString(Date(), "mmHHddMMyyyy")
            if (isCustomtHandle) {
                return runOperationWithoutHandle {
                    traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)
                }
            } else {
                return runOperationWithDefaultHandle {
                    traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)
                }
            }
        }

        suspend private fun runOperationWithoutHandle(func: suspend () -> Response<*>): Response<*> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response: Response<*> = func() // in runtime replace by method body (e.g. traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList())
            response
        }

        suspend private fun runOperationWithDefaultHandle(func: suspend () -> Response<*>): TransportResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response: Response<*> = func() // in runtime replace by method body (e.g. traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList())
                if (response.isSuccessful) { // status (200-299)
                    onSuccess(response)
                } else {// error - status (300-599)
                    val errorResponse: ErrorResponse = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
                    onError(errorResponse)
                }
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                val errorResponse = ErrorResponse()
                errorResponse.setCode(SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_CODE)
                errorResponse.message = MyApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.service_unavailable)
                onError(errorResponse)
            }
}
```

When `isCustomtHandle` is **true** then call lambda "`runOperationWithoutHandle`". This lambda **ONLY** execute http request and not handle.

When `isCustomtHandle` is **false** then call lambda "`runOperationWithDefaultHandle`". This lambda execute http request **and** handle response.

OK. This work fine.

But as you can see has **duplicate** on line

```
traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)
```

and

line

```
traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()
```

How I can remove this duplicate? I want to call lines

```
traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)
```

and

```
traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()
```

only once.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you add an anonymous suspending function locally inside the `executeTraderOperation` function and call that from the two branches of the `if` statement?  e.g.

```
suspend fun executeTraderOperation(...): Any {
    ...
    suspend fun execOperation() = traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(
        traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)

    if (isCustomtHandle) {
        return runOperationWithoutHandle(::execOperation)
    } else {
        return runOperationWithDefaultHandle(::execOperation)
    }
```